# Is there a command to get the pods details for a specific service deployed on openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I currently need to get the number of pods running for a existing service and the pod status from the jenkins pipeline. Is there an oc command that can serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `oc describe` on the `deploymentconfig` for your application you can see the replica count for the application. For example:

```
$ oc describe dc/blog
Name:       blog
Namespace:  book
Created:    2 weeks ago
Labels:     app=blog
Annotations:    openshift.io/generated-by=OpenShiftNewApp
Latest Version: 1
Selector:   app=blog,deploymentconfig=blog
Replicas:   1
Triggers:   Config, Image(blog-django-py@latest, auto=true)
Strategy:   Rolling
...
```

Also note the labels. You can get a list of pods for the actual deployment using a label selector when running `oc get pods`. For example:

```
$ oc get pods --selector app=blog
NAME           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
blog-1-vqj1x   1/1       Running   0          15d
```

This will show the status of the pods.